# Trying to create a virtual environment in python 3.5 version

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using command prompt, trying to create a virtual environment.

Here is the prompt I am typing in:

```
C:\Users\Eric>cd d3stryr-3stripes-master

C:\Users\Eric\d3stryr-3stripes-master>virtualenv -p python3 --no-site-packages env
```

The error is:

```
The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist
```

I am completely lost as to why this doesn't exist.

Comment: Try instead providing the full path, e.g., `/usr/bin/python3` or whatever the path to your Python executable is (this can be found with `which python3`).

Comment: so it would be:

Comment: so it would be?:

virtualenv /usr/bin/python3 --no-site-packages env

Comment: Don't forget the `-p` or `--python=...`, but yes: `virtualenv -p path/to/python3 --no-site-packages env`

Comment: Provide actual commands used in your question, not in an attached image

Comment: I'm confused..... So I'm trying to run some script files that are in a folder. This folder is in C:\Users\Eric\d3stryr-3stripes-master. 

What would I type in after C:\Users\Eric\d3stryr-3stripes-master>  to create the virtual env?

Comment: Looking again at your image I see that you are on Window, and I am not sure how to get it to work in that case. You will need to enter the same command you entered in your screenshot, but instead of just `python3` you will need to provide the path to your Python3 executable, but I am not sure where this is on Windows...

Comment: @donkopotamus updated with commands, not sure if you can help or not.

Comment: It sounds like python3 is not in your paths. Read 3.3.1 in this https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: @EmettSpeer hm.... I've uninstalled and reinstalled following those directions. Still cant seem to figure it out.  Here's what I'm trying to do.

1) Navigate to the d3stryr-3stripes-master folder
C:\Users\Eric\d3stryr-3stripes-master>

Comment: @EmettSpeer

2) Create a virtual environment:
virtualenv -p python3 --no-site-packages env
C:\Users\Eric\d3stryr-3stripes-master>virtualenv -p python3 --no-site-packages env

^^ that is where I get the error

Comment: @GreenSaucer42 Have you tried `virtualenv -p "C:\PATH TO PYTHON3.exe" --so-site-packages myvenv`?

Comment: @EmettSpeer do I literally type "path to python3.exe" ?

Comment: @GreenSaucer42 This will change depending on where you installed python on your system but will look something like this. `virtualenv -p "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\python.exe" --no-site-packages myvenv`.

Comment: @EmettSpeer I typed python in on the windows search bar and right clicked python3.5 -> open file location and literally took the destination 
C:\Users\Eric\d3stryr-3stripes-master>virtualenv -p "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.5\python.exe" --no-site-packages myvenv

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: @EmettSpeer yes, I got it to work, had to move python to that file destination. Wondering if you could help me with something else. When I try and run a .py file, I get an error that says "Import error: no module name 'jinja2'

Comment: Have you installed jinja2 yet?

Comment: @EmettSpeer i haven't

Comment: @GreenSaucer42 you may want to give this a watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnpC_Ib_lbc

Comment: @EmettSpeer can i install it by typing "pip install Jinja2"

Comment: @GreenSaucer42 I'm not sure. I don't use Windows for anything and I hear that it can be different.

Comment: @EmettSpeer Ok, so I got everything working. I'm running a script that opens the web browser. When the script runs, it tries to open google chrome but I get an error that says Google Chrome cannot read and write to its data directory: ChromeFolder. 

Any Suggestions?

Comment: @GreenSaucer42 I think this would be a new question with an example of your code and details about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This will change depending on where you installed python on your system but will look something like this.

```
virtualenv -p "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\python.exe" --no-site-packages myvenv
```